# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException for autowired bean when java bean configuration location is changed from src/main/java to src/test/java

Tags: spring, junit, spring-boot

I have an existing spring boot application and I am adding `junit tests` to it. The project has `Configuration.java` in src/main/java folder containing  the bean configuration.

In my `junit` class when I refer to configuration file present in location src/main using

```
  @SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Configuration.class)
```

then the Autowired bean intializes properly. However when I copy the  same configuration file in src/test/java and refer it using Configuration

```
 @SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = TestConfig.class)
```

then the autowire bean fails to initilize giving exception `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`.

Its the same configuration java file. The bean I am autowiring is present in src/main/java. Does the location of bean configuration java files affects the bean initialization ? If Yes, how to resolve it ?

Note: I am copying the same config java file to src/test/java as I need some different property while testing.

Comment: Why copy... Just create a new one which only contains the differences, then load both files... Don't duplicate the configuration.

Comment: in this case how to select which file to load while running the test and while running the main application?

Comment: Let the test load both the main and test config. Your application doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it be using `basepackage` attribute of `@ComponentScan` as shown below(in the config file of src/test/java have put the package name belonging to package in src/main/java).

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = CommandLineRunner.class),basePackages = "com.mypackage")
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={MetricRepositoryAutoConfiguration.class})
public class TestConfiguration  {
```